# object doesn't support this property or method btoa

Tags: javascript

I know there is already a question on here with solutions for this but I have little understanding of javascript and I can't seem to figure out what they are saying to add in or where. The link to it is here: [IExplorer: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'btoa'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286745/iexplorer-script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-btoa)

Can someone explain to me what they are doing to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Not all browsers support .btoa(), so you have to polyfill it for non-supporting browser by adding [this script](https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js/blob/master/base64.js)

Comment: Somewhere, your script (or a library that your script uses) tries to call `window.btoa`. That function doesn't exist in older versions of IE. Instead, you must include a separate JS file (in a `<script>` tag) that adds the `btoa` function to the `window` object. Such a script is called a "shim" or "polyfill" that manually fills in some methods that aren't natively supported in certain browsers. The linked script there (https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js) is such a shim for `btoa`.

Comment: @adeneo do I just add this into my file and it should work or do I need to call to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older browsers may not support [`Window.bota`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.btoa), which is basically an oddly-named method to convert strings to base64 representations, as you probably know.

Making new functionality available in older browsers is called "polyfilling".  Put the script `base64.js` ([download](https://raw.github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js/master/base64.js)) or `base64.min.js` ([download](https://raw.github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js/master/base64.min.js)) on your website (I'm going to assume you're using the latter, and putting it in the `/js/vendor` directory), and reference it thusly (*before* you need to use `Window.bota`):

```
<script src="/js/vendor/base64.min.js"></script>
```

If the browser is newer, this script won't do anything (i.e., it won't replace the existing `Window.btoa` implementation).  If the browser is older, it will now have the functionality.

If you want to avoid the additional HTTP request required to read `base64.min.js`, you can use [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/):

```
yepnope({
  test: window.btoa && window.atob,
  nope: '/js/vendor/base64.js',
  callback: function () {
    // `btoa` and `atob` are now safe to use
  }
});
```

Comment: Joshua, it's really hard to answer that question without knowing what you're doing, or what motivated your original question.  If you need to use `Window.btoa`, you must add the polyfill _before_ you use `Window.btoa`...I'm not sure what else you're confused about.

Comment: If I use the base64 files do I need to add the yepnope function? But I believe anyone using this program will have a newer browser so can I just use the yepnope function without base64?

Comment: ...I just don't understand if I add the polyfill inside the function or if its meant to go outside the function?

Comment: As I indicate in my answer, using yepnope is optional: that will just save an extra HTTP request if they're using a newer browser.  (However, if this is the only thing you're using yepnope for, then you've got the HTTP request to load yepnope, so you're not gaining anything there).  Sounds to me like you should ignore yepnope, and just include `base64.min.js` and call it a day.  I'm just trying to give you the complete picture.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! One more question though...When I'm calling to the script for base64 where exactly do I do this? My script for the tableToExcel function is in its own jscript file btw.

Comment: You need to call that before you link in your `tableToExcel` function.  For example, if your script is in `/js/tableToExcel.js`, and you link it in in the `<head>` section of your HTML, you would do this: `<script src='/js/vendor/base64.min.js'></script><script src='/js/tableToExcel.js'></script>`

Comment: ok thanks! If you don't mind me asking though, how does it know to use that as the polyfill? I mean its never called to in the program.

Comment: Basically, the script checks for the existence of `Windows.btoa`.  If it's present, it doesn't do anything.  If it's not, it creates the method.

Comment: Ok thanks. I know when I just tried it, it showed the page trying to load but wouldn't bring up the download for the table. I guess I messed something else up somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

add this line on the header of your page, and it will be fixed

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: bota isn't available on IE<10, so adding that will do nothing for the developer